# How to generate an associative algebra given a Lie subalgebra

Tags: lie-algebras, algebraic-groups, semisimple-lie-algebras

I am new to the study of Lie algebras and particularly algebraic Lie algebras. In the paper

*Chevalley, Claude*, [**Algebraic Lie algebras**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1969217), Ann. Math. (2) 48, 91-100 (1947). [ZBL0032.25202](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0032.25202).

the author states

> Let  ${h}$ be an abelian subalgebra of $gl(n;K)$ which has a basis ${B_1,B_2,,,,,B_r}$ composed of semisimple matrices. Then every matrix in ${h}$ is semisimple and the identity matrix of ${h}$ into $gl(n;K)$ is a semisimple representation of ${h}$.

The proof begins with Let ${B}$ be the associative algebra generated by the elements of ${h}$ and unit matrix E.
I do not understand how to generate an associative algebra when the multiplication is already predefined in the algebra.
Any explanation would be of great help.

Comment: There are *two* algebra structures here. One is the Lie Algebra structure and the other is the associative algebra of matrices. Perhaps the latter is what is meant.

Comment: We can define a Lie subalgebra in the Lie algebra ${\rm End}(V)$ with product $[A,B]=AB-BA$, and at the same time an associative subalgebra of the associative algebra ${\rm End}(V)$ with product $AB$. So we have *two different algebra multiplications*.

Comment: Ok.. I see it.. thanks to both of you